# Updated Wordpress site url but hyperlinks are still unchanged

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated two site urls in the database. However, hyperlinks such as Top Menu are still redirecting to the old site. Any idea what it is? I'm new to WP. Thanks.

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://example.com');  
update_option('home', 'http://example.com');
```

Edited:

```
<a <?php if( $item->hasLinkClasses() ) : ?>class="<?php echo $item->getLinkClasses(); ?>"<?php endif;?> <?php if( $item->hasLink() ) : ?>href="<?php echo $item->getLink();?>"<?php endif;?> <?php if( $item->getTarget() ) : ?>target="<?php echo $item->getTarget();?>"<?php endif;?> <?php if( $item->hasLinkAttribs() ) : ?> <?php echo $item->getLinkAttribs(); ?><?php endif;?>>

            <?php if ($item->getLevel() == 0) : ?>
            <span class="rt-item-border"></span>
```

Comment: Can you give the code of the menu ?

Comment: @Farzad code added. It's Gantry Framework.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is (I've used it several times) to use [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to update the urls in database because there are urls saved in database that needs to be changed. Download that script and follow the instruction on the site `INSTALLATION & USE` about the usage.

You have to upload it to your root directory of `WordPress` installation and run the script using something like `http://example.com/searchandreplace.php`, you should rename it before you upload it to your server.

> **Important:** Once you use it then must remove the script from your server.

Answer (score 0):

search check your database for this url is changed or not.
static url will work same on server or localhost.